# QgsProcessingParameterString(), Store user input?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm adding some stuff to a QGIS plugin and trying to figure out how to work with user inputs. In this case, the user input is a string, which seems simple to work with, but I can't find an example of it anywhere.

I am not using Qt Designer to design my interface for the dialog box, I'm instead using various methods from the [QgsProcessingParameters class](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingParameters.html). Specifically I am using QgsProcessingParameterString.

In the plugin, I'm using the initAlgorithm and adding a line for the user to input a string. Here is the code:

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config):

#Add String as input
    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterString(
            self.INPUT_TITLE,
            self.tr('Input title string (Optional)')
        )
    )
```

Now in the processAlgorithm I use a method .parameterAsString

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    """This actually does the processing for creating the print layout and exporting as .pdf"""

    log = feedback.setProgressText

    input_title = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT_TITLE, context)

    log(print the user input)
```

I'm just trying to print the user input in this example.
How do I get the value the user input (a string)? I want to create a variable which stores the user input as a string. I can use the string later in my program.

And are there any examples of using QgsProcessingAlgorithm.parameterAsString?

Comment: What you've got is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

@ndawson's simple comment gave me the confidence I was actually on the right track

I will elaborate on my own question. 
In the processAlgorithm, the log prints stuff to the console when running the plugin.
I define input_title as the following:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

    log = feedback.setProgressText

    input_title = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT_TITLE, context)
```

input_title is now just a string, with the text the user wrote in the dialog box of the plugin. I was definitely overthinking this earlier.

While running the plugin, if I want to return the user's input text in the "log" tab of my plugin, I can do:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

    log = feedback.setProgressText

    input_title = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT_TITLE, context)

    log(input_title)      #this prints input_title in plugin log
```

Alternatively, I can work with vector or raster objects in the same way. Here is an example with a vector object:
First, create your class and create constants to refer to parameters. In the initAlgorithm, define an vector input field. Then in the processAlgorithm you can work with the vector object.

```
class ClassName(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT_VECTOR = 'INPUT_VECTOR'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config):
    """Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm"""

        #Add Vector Layer as input
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
                self.INPUT_VECTOR,
                self.tr('Choose vector layer as input'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        log = feedback.setProgressText

        input_vector = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_VECTOR, context)

        log(input_vector.name())        #use all the regular attributes and methods for a vector object
```

I hope this helps someone other than me.